# Polymer is not installing in mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install polymer in my mac machine using npm. I have done all the required config settings to work npm behind proxy. Still i am not able to install the polymer. Please check the error shown in the screen shot. Can anyone help me to find the solution of this?

[image]

Comment: Can you install anything else through npm? Can you connect to github port 22 any other way…?

Comment: Yes i am able to install express, angular etc. But only for polymer i am getting this issue.

Comment: `polymer-cli` depends on something that is hosted on GitHub (not the NPM repo), and your machine can't connect to GitHub port 22 for whatever reason. Notice the `ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out` error message.

Comment: @robertklep Could you please narrow down the possible reasons as I am new to mac.

Comment: @suyesh firewall, Little Snitch-type software, proxy, government filter, bad internet connection/provider, it's difficult to say. I assume that your Mac does have a working internet connection (you should be able to access https://github.com)